# How to specify default export and same non-default export non-redundantly?

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I currently export from a file `a.ts` like follows:

```
const a = 3;
const b = 'xyz';
const c = false;
type D = null | undefined;
export {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  type D,
};
export default {
  a,
  b,
  c,
}; // Note that this is an object {a: a, b: b, c: c}; cannot export D here
```

and I want to import it in a file `b.ts` (in the same directory) as follows:

```
import x from './a';
import * as y from './a';
import {c, type D} from './a';
const a = x.a;
const b = y.b;
```

This all works as intended. The only problem is that I have to specify the non-default exports and the default export twice although they are identical at value level (not sure about what to do with `type D` though). In my real case, there are not four variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `D` but dozens of them and also not a single file `a.ts` but dozens of files with this structure, making maintainance difficult. So, is there a way to get of the redundancy?

Comment: Why bother with a default export here when you can simply `import * as y from './a';` and get all named exports as one item? It's usually best to only have one way to import a thing.

Comment: According to the way you defined y, you can also use `const {a, b} = y`

Comment: One possible way is to not bother with default export or even star import, and just `import { a, b, c, type D } from './a'; `